How do I create RANDOM character strings in postscript?
I am trying to write a postscript document that will output strings of 5 random characters.
I can make an array of 26 upper case letter A-Z
but I cannot work out how to concatinate five random indexes to a string.
RAND seems not to be random. I cannot figure out how to twiddle the seed or randomize RAND. I read the green,blue books and my head hurts trying to locate this obscure requirement.
in plain english:
eg.  array = "A,B,C,...X,Y,Z"
rand_idx = int rand mod 26
outputstring = char(rand_idx)+char(rand_idx)+char(rand_idx)+char(rand_idx)+char(rand_idx)...repeat
OUTPUT = SVDRT KHSTE NCSDE SSGYP DISVT
MY CODE FAILS WHEN TRYING TO GENERATE RANDOM NUMBERS WITH -RAND-
THE OUTPUT REPEATS THE SAME STRINGS AT UNPREDICTABLE INTERVALS.
CODE
/inch {72 mul} def
/Times-Roman findfont 15 scalefont setfont

/letterArray [(A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H) (I) (J) (K) (L) (M) (N) (O) (P) (Q) (R) (S) (T) (U) (V) (W) (X) (Y) (Z)] def

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1 inch 10 inch moveto
        realtime  srand        
6{
    5{
        /rrr {rand 26 mod} def
        letterArray rrr get show
        } repeat (   ) show
} repeat
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1 inch 9 inch moveto
        realtime srand
6{
    5{
        /rrr {rand 26 mod} def
        letterArray rrr get show
        } repeat (   ) show
} repeat
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
1 inch 8 inch moveto
        realtime srand
6{
    5{
        /rrr {rand 26 mod} def
        letterArray rrr get show
        } repeat (   ) show
} repeat
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

showpage

% THE OUTPUT IS DEFINITELY NOT RANDOM. AM I USING THE WRONG OPERATOR?

%   AJFHN PDZZU BNLAD NZABD EZTUO NGZEC
%   WRVEW ORLPS YKNGT QKMAN RNUIP OCYTP
%   WRVEW ORLPS YKNGT QKMAN RNUIP OCYTP


letterArray 5 get show should work - except that you forgot the def to actually assign the alphabet to letterArray.

After you changed your code, the problem is now that you're calling srand constantly - sometimes faster than the output from realtime is changing.  You don't need srand at all, and if you are going to call it, once is all you need.
